# Remove class from HTML when one of two links are clicked (both have same class)

Tags: javascript, html, queryselector

I have a UI element that has two panels. Only one is visible at any given time so each panel has its own close link. Both these links should perform the same action - closing/hiding the element.

Initially I thought I could do this by toggling the class on `html` and have the same class applied to the link that opens the UI element and the two that close it (below) but this didn't work.

```
const html = document.querySelector('html');
const button = document.querySelector('.trigger-cart');

button.addEventListener('click', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  html.classList.toggle('cart-visible');
});
```

I've included an example of where my code is add now. I have remove the toggle for separate add/remove declarations. This is better but only the first close button works and the one that follows in the markup doesn't fire at all. I tried using `querySelectorAll` but that doesn't seem to work either?

Can someone help me with this? Just getting the close buttons working is the priority but I might have several links on the page that could in theory open this UI element. Which is why I thought using a single class to toggle the class on `html` might be best initially.

```js
/* const html = document.querySelector('html');
const button = document.querySelector('.trigger-cart');

button.addEventListener('click', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  html.classList.toggle('cart-visible');
});
 */

const html = document.querySelector('html');
const btnOpen = document.querySelector('.trigger-cart');
const btnClose = document.querySelector('.close-cart');

btnOpen.addEventListener('click', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  html.classList.add('cart-visible');
});

btnClose.addEventListener('click', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  html.classList.remove('cart-visible');
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.cart {
  background: #eee;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: -375px;
  transition: right .5s;
  width: 375px;
}

.cart-visible .cart {
  right: 0;
}

.panel-one,
.panel-two {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 50vw;
  align-content: center;
}

.panel-two {
  background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="trigger-cart">Display Cart</a>

<div class="cart">
  <div class="panel-one">
    <a href="#" class="close-cart">Close Link</a>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-two">
    <a href="#" class="close-cart">Close Link</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You have multiple link elements with the same class `close-cart` and using `querySelector` to get them will return only the first link element, that's why only the first link is working.**

To resolve this-

1. Use the `document. querySelectorAll()` method to find all elements of class `close-cart`.
2. Use the `forEach()` loop to iterate over the collection of the elements.
3. And then use `addEventListener()` method to add an event listener to each element.

Here is the working demo-

```js
/* const html = document.querySelector('html');
const button = document.querySelector('.trigger-cart');

button.addEventListener('click', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  html.classList.toggle('cart-visible');
});
 */

const html = document.querySelector('html');
const btnOpen = document.querySelector('.trigger-cart');
const allCloseButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.close-cart');

allCloseButtons.forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('click', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    html.classList.remove('cart-visible');
  });
});


btnOpen.addEventListener('click', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  html.classList.add('cart-visible');
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.cart {
  background: #eee;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: -375px;
  transition: right .5s;
  width: 375px;
}

.cart-visible .cart {
  right: 0;
}

.panel-one,
.panel-two {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 50vw;
  align-content: center;
}

.panel-two {
  background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="trigger-cart">Display Cart</a>

<div class="cart">
  <div class="panel-one">
    <a href="#" class="close-cart">Close Link</a>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-two">
    <a href="#" class="close-cart">Close Link</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Just out but will test when I get back. Out of interest, do you think the separate add/remove approach is correct. Or would a toggle be better? Or would that just not work in this situation anyways?

Comment: Both approaches are completely identical. A toggle adds a class when the element doesn't have this and remove the class if the element has it which is the exact output that is done by manual adding and removing methods.

Comment: Cool, I think I'll stick with add/remove as I want to add a `setTimeout` to remove another class on a child element after the menu has closed with a delay. But good to know I could use the same approach with `querySelectorAll` and `forEach` if I wanted to toggle. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The query selector method returns the first child,You can change your code like this

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
      html,
      body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }

      .cart {
        background: #eee;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        height: 100vh;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        right: -375px;
        transition: right 0.5s;
        width: 375px;
      }

      .cart-visible .cart {
        right: 0;
      }

      .panel-one,
      .panel-two {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        height: 50vw;
        align-content: center;
      }

      .panel-two {
        background: #ddd;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <section id="cart_section">
      <a class="trigger-cart">Display Cart</a>

      <div class="cart">
        <div class="panel-one">
          <a class="close-cart" onclick="closeCart()">Close Link</a>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-two">
          <a class="close-cart" onclick="closeCart()">Close Link</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <script> 

      const btnOpen = document.querySelector(".trigger-cart");
      const btnClose = document.querySelector(".close-cart");
      const cart_section = document.getElementById("cart_section");

      btnOpen.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        cart_section.classList.add("cart-visible");
      });

      function closeCart() {
        cart_section.classList.remove("cart-visible");
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```